# MSI Install Outlook plug-in challenges

Tags: outlook, windows-installer, plugins

I have created an Outlook plug-in and I am having some challenges around installing the system. The issue I am having relates to the situation where a user is applying an update to my plug-in and has Outlook running while they apply the update via the MSI. Currently a window will be displaying informing the user that Outlook is running and they should close Outlook before continuing. The problem is though that they can elect to continue and reboot Outlook later. If that happens then my app is not completely installed and corruption with one of my data files can occur. I see two possible issues that I was hoping for ideas:

1. Is there anyway that I can eliminate the "Continue and reboot later" option that appears when Outlook is running during my MSI install?
2. If option #1 isn't possible, how can I add some of my own files to the list of files that the MSI keeps that are overwritten when Outlook is rebooted?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

One possible, though frowned upon, solution is to write a CustomAction that will go look for open Outlook windows and close them.  Generally you should warn your users you're about to close their application and give them the opportunity to not close it and cancel the install.

I have, unfortunately, used this solution more times than I care to admit in order to install Internet Explorer plug-ins.

There may be other solutions.